# iOS: How to present UIAlertController in iCloud Singleton? (Swift)

Tags: ios, singleton, icloud, uialertcontroller

I'm creating a `Singleton` to manage my iCloud setup and configuration.

As part of the iCloud Design Guide the document states:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html

**Listing 1-4**  Inviting the user to use iCloud

```
if (currentiCloudToken && firstLaunchWithiCloudAvailable) {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle: @"Choose Storage Option"
                              message: @"Should documents be stored in iCloud and
                                            available on all your devices?"
                             delegate: self
                    cancelButtonTitle: @"Local Only"
                    otherButtonTitles: @"Use iCloud", nil];
[alert show];
}
```

I've converted this to a UIAlertController in Swift but how can I run `self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` from my singleton?

Obviously my singleton `does not have a member named 'presentViewController'`

Is there anyway to do this or do I need to setup a Post Notification, present the Alert somewhere else in my program and then save/retrieve the user's selection?

Answer (score 0):

1) Add custom protocol delegate to your singleton, and this delegate will return UIViewController instance

```
protocol TestSingletonDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func responderViewControllerForTestSingleton(singleton: TestSingleton)->UIViewController
}
```

And in your class:

```
let delegate: TestSingletonDelegate
func presentAlertView() {
    let alertView = UIAlertView();
    if (self.delegate.respondsToSelector("responderViewControllerForTestSingleton:")) {
        let viewController = self.delegate.responderViewControllerForTestSingleton(TestSingleton())
        viewController.presentViewController(alertView, animated: YES, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

2) Add instance var to your singleton class, and story UIViewController variable there

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it in my case by simply returning the alertController to the singleton and then presenting it there.

In the AlertView Class I have the below code for a simple alert that can take the title and message as input and display's only one OK button to dismiss the alert:

```
func alert(#alertTitle: String, alertMessage: String) -> UIAlertController {

    var alertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    var okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

    alertController.addAction(okButton)

    return alertController

}
```

Note that in the above method I am not presenting the alert controller to the view rather just returning it to whom ever is calling the method.

Then in the class where I called the method I am doing the below code:

** Just a note that the class where I am calling the alert is a ViewController in Objective-C. I'll provide swift code below as well**

```
// Creating an instance of the AlertView class and initializing it
AlertView *testAlert = [[AlertView alloc] init];

/* Creating a UIAlertController object and then calling the method I created in the AlertView class. This way the returned UIAlertController will be assigned to this UIAlertController
*/

UIAlertController *alertController = [testAlert alertWithAlertTitle:@"Genius!" alertMessage:@"Pure Genius"];


// Finally presenting the alert controller
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:true completion:nil];
```

NOTE: that I've found that you have to do this outside of ViewDidLoad. It doesn't work in ViewDidLoad and gives the below error:

```
Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x1555118f0> on <ViewController: 0x155509790> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Instead you can do this in viewDidAppear method.

Now Swift Version of ViewController:

```
// Created a function to show the alert
func showAlert() {

    // Creating an instance of the AlertView class and initializing it
    var testAlert : AlertView = AlertView()

    /* Creating a UIAlertController object and then calling the method I created in the AlertView class. This way the returned UIAlertController will be assigned to this UIAlertController
    */
    var alertController : UIAlertController = testAlert.alert(alertTitle: "Genius", alertMessage: "Pure Genius")


    // Finally presenting the alert controller
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

One more thing if you are trying to show this alert in a Singleton outside of the ViewController then you can retrieve the top view controller as below and then present the alert controller to it:

Objective - C:

```
UIViewController *topViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

[topViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:true completion:nil];
```

Swift:

```
if let topViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController? {

        topViewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class SharedDataSingleton  {

    init(){

        //println("Hellow World")
    }


    var sample = "Hellow word"

    func showAlertView(title alerTitle:String ,message alertMessage:String, preferredStyle style:UIAlertControllerStyle, okLabel: String, cancelLabel: String, targetViewController: UIViewController,okHandler: ((UIAlertAction!) -> Void)!, cancelHandler: ((UIAlertAction!) -> Void)!){

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: alerTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: style)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: okLabel, style: .Default, handler: okHandler)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelLabel, style: .Default,handler: cancelHandler)

            // Add Actions
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            // Present Alert Controller
            targetViewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }





}

let sharedDataSingletonInstance = SharedDataSingleton()


> Access the values like  below


sharedDataSingletonInstance.showAlertView(title: "Sample",
message: "Sample", 
preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert, 
okLabel: "Ok", 
cancelLabel: "Cancel",
targetViewController: self, 
okHandler: { (action) -> Void in
            println("The user is not okay.")
            }, 
cancelHandler: { (action) -> Void in
                println("The user is not okay.")
        })


    }



> Global Variables can be also accessed anywhere in our project 

sharedDataSingletonInstance.sample
```

Comment: Please add some (simple) text introducing your answer, thanks.